# Python-3.8.2 installation from source causes undefined reference to `SSL_new' on python installation?

Tags: python, pip, openssl, ubuntu-18.04, python-3.8

I am trying to install python3.8.2 from python source by following this [link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04/), everything works fine except `ssl` module.

when i try command like below.

> ./configure --with-openssl=/usr --enable-optimizations

config.log looks like below

```
configure:17204: checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr
configure:17211: result: yes
configure:17227: checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works
Trying link with OPENSSL_LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib; OPENSSL_LIBS=-lssl -lcrypto; OPENSSL_INCLUDES=- 
I/usr/include
configure:17249: gcc -pthread -o conftest  -I/usr/include   -L/usr/lib conftest.c -lssl - 
lcrypto -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm >&5
/tmp/ccnYKZ7g.o: In function `main':
conftest.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `SSL_new'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and when i run

> make -j 8

am getting error like follow

```
Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires an OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1 compatible libssl with 
X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by following the steps provided in in this [link](https://techglimpse.com/install-python-openssl-support-tutorial/)

Step1:

```
$ wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz
```

Step2:

```
$ tar -xf openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz
```

Step3:

```
$ cd openssl-1.1.1g
```

Step4:

```
./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl
```

Note:

> By default openssl will be installed under /usr/local/ssl. If you do not want to mess with existing SSL installation, then install it in a different directory.

Step5:

```
$ make
$ make test
$ make install
```

Then i navigate to python installed dir. followed the below steps

```
$ ./configure --with-openssl=/usr --enable-optimizations
$ make -j 8
```

Comment: For the last step of configuring python build, I needed ```--with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl```